# Node.js: How to create XML files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, node.js

Is there a good way to create XML files? For example, like the Builder for Rails (or any other way)?

Thanks

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It looks like the [xmlbuilder-js](https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js) library may do this for you. If you have npm installed, you can `npm install xmlbuilder`.

It will let you do this (taken from their example):

```
var builder = require('xmlbuilder');
var doc = builder.create('root');

doc.ele('xmlbuilder')
    .att('for', 'node-js')
    .ele('repo')
      .att('type', 'git')
      .txt('git://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js.git') 
    .up()
  .up()
  .ele('test')
    .txt('complete');

console.log(doc.toString({ pretty: true }));
```

which will result in:

```
<root>
  <xmlbuilder for="node-js">
    <repo type="git">git://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js.git</repo>
  </xmlbuilder>
  <test>complete</test>
</root>
```

Comment: I'm having a small issue with this. I posted on [github](https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js/issues/23) if you're interested in lending a hand.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, here i found a tutorial on this topic, I hope it will be helpful for someone. https://programmerblog.net/generate-xml-with-nodejs-and-mysql/

Comment: Can I write the result on a .xml file?

Comment: @BiruelRick, it will give you a string formattd as `xml`. You can use `fs` module to write to a file. Hope this helps

Comment: The api has changed a bit, the latest documentation is available [here](https://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js)

Answer (score 5):

recent changes to xmlbuilder require root element name passed to `create()`

see working example

```
var builder = require('xmlbuilder');
var doc = builder.create('root')
  .ele('xmlbuilder')
    .att('for', 'node-js')
    .ele('repo')
      .att('type', 'git')
      .txt('git://github.com/oozcitak/xmlbuilder-js.git') 
      .up()
    .up()
  .ele('test')
  .txt('complete')
.end({ pretty: true });
console.log(doc.toString());
```

Answer (score 4):

`xmlbuilder` was discontinued and replaced by `xmlbuilder2`, which has been redesigned from the ground up to be fully conforming to the [modern DOM specification](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/).

To install `xmlbuilder2` using `npm`:

```
npm install xmlbuilder2
```

An example, from their home page, for creating a new XML file with it:

```
const { create } = require('xmlbuilder2');

const root = create({ version: '1.0' })
  .ele('root', { att: 'val' })
    .ele('foo')
      .ele('bar').txt('foobar').up()
    .up()
    .ele('baz').up()
  .up();

// convert the XML tree to string
const xml = root.end({ prettyPrint: true });
console.log(xml);
```

Will result in:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root att="val">
  <foo>
    <bar>foobar</bar>
  </foo>
  <baz/>
</root>
```