# Build XML using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xml, node.js

I am new to NodeJS, and I've setup a little webserver. Now I want to be able to use my old html files, which at server side on PHP, which I now want to translate to JavaScript. I have a function in my PHP files, which retrieves information from MySQL and turns it into a XML document and sends it to the client.

So now I want to build a XML 'file' using JavaScript. I am familiar with that, because the JavaScript on client-side would turn the XML file into a table. So I searched the internet and found nothing about:

1. Beginning a XML file (so not importing one)
2. Building an XML file like you handling the DOM in the browser, with that I mean being able to use functions like `getElementsByTagName()`, `createElement` and `setAttribute()` for instance.

My excuses where my English is not the best, 'cause I'm a dutch guy. I hope that doesn't influence an answer :).

Thanks,

Comment: Hello, you should have started with a search on npm, and maybe then realize you are going the wrong way ;-) If you come in the nodeJS world, why not giving up on XML and use JSON?

Comment: I could do that, the reason I wanted to stick to XML is because the client-side is made for XML; many of my JavaScript code in my HTML files deal with XML, and I prefer not to rewrite them too.

Comment: Well then you should look at https://www.npmjs.org/package/xml for example and then comme back if you have problem with it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js: How to create XML files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7285393/node-js-how-to-create-xml-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an package called [xmldom](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xmldom) that provides an implementation of the DOM Api for node.js

```
npm install xmldom
```

If you want support for XPath with `document.evaluate()`, check out [xpath](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xpath) package.

```
npm install xpath
```

Answer (score 1):

I recomand you use `xmlbuilder` package.

```
npm install xmlbuilder
```

the full documentation is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlbuilder)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [damn-simple-xml](https://www.npmjs.com/package/damn-simple-xml). It's really well documented. You'll work with your javascript object until you need to serialized it to XML.